# Angular control match is not known

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an Angular custom directive as the following:

```js
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function numericValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const testNumericPattern = '/^[0-9]{1,6}/g';
    if (!control.value) {
      return null;
    }
    const isValidNumeric = control.value.match(testNumericPattern);
    if (!isValidNumeric) {
      return { value: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
```

and my test is the following:

```js
describe('NumericValidatorDirective', () => {
  const customNumber = new FormControl('', [numericValidator()]);

  it('should gives error when number is less than 0', () => {
    customNumber.patchValue(-1);
    expect(customNumber.valid).toBeFalsy();
  });

  fit('should gives error when a number is more than 999999', () => {
    customNumber.patchValue(999999);
    expect(customNumber.valid).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

But the issue is that when I run tests I get the following error:

> TypeError: control.value.match is not a function

despite that I have removed the check `if (!control.value) {` and I still have the same issue when I test.

Any idea why this issue appear, cause it does not seems logic to me?

Comment: numbers don't have a `match` method, strings do. So instead of `patchValue(1)`, do `patchValue("1")`.

Comment: Also, consider typecasting `value` when accessing it, since it has the type `any` when initially accessed.

Comment: Well, it did the job and I have fixed it, thanks! but what do you mean by consider typecasing `value` as for now I'm using `value` and not something else? also now I can see that my regex is failing cause somehow it is a wrong matchnig pattern, any idea too?